# iis web page load slowly in morning first load

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have a IIS server which hosted asp.net application, when a page first loaded daily, it will be slow for 10 to 15 seconds. Maybe it is after recycling. I cannot simulate the situation in my testing server, even I recycled the iis, it can still load quickly in my testing iis server. How can I find out what is causing it and how can I simulate it in my test server?

Comment: See the Recycle settings in IIS. It's a setting of an individual AppPool

Comment: And "advanced settings > Idle time out" If the site is not served in xx minutes it will shut down (like in the middle of the night) and will do the same as a recycle when it is first loaded (like in the morning).

Comment: People usually use performance profilers to collect information about slowness and tell what is the culprit. So, you should do the same instead of guessing what might be wrong.

Comment: This is by design. For site not been used for some time, then web server will shut down the app pool, return memory to the server, and save world poverty in terms of  power use, ram use, and server side resources use.  So, the first time use and slow start is often the compiling of the asp.net web site. However, in a low volume and low use server system, the web site can be setup to sleep and return the valuable resources to the server.  So, this so called lazy loading and tossing the site and stopping appPool is standard fair. You can disable this, and set startmode to "always running"

Comment: Can I call a link to the website once in morning to let it become quick after the call of the link?

Comment: I try to set the idle timeout to 1 minute, but the slow responding time is not happened after 1 minute, it's behaviour is different from the idle of overnight. How can I simulate the overnight idle?

Comment: Use a performance profiler to analyze the initialization process of your web application. That should explain why it takes so long to respond to the first request.